# How to deal with DBGrid control?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
    SQL> desc admin
                 Name Null? Type
           -------------------------------------
                NAME VARCHAR2(20)
                PRIVILEDGE VARCHAR2(20)
                CODE NUMBER(38)
                PASS VARCHAR2(20)

              Private Sub Form_Load()
              Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
              If RS.State = 1 Then RS.Close
              opencn
              RS.Open "ADMIN", CN, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
              Set DBGrid1.DataSource = RS
RS.Close
End Sub
```

Error I'm getting

```
*Error 430 at line : Set DBGrid1.DataSource = RS
Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface*
```

Answer (score 0):

The Data Bound Grid (DBGrid) is for use with DAO, while the DataGrid is for use with ADO.

In the toolbox: right click, select 'Components...', and be sure `'Microsoft DataGrid Control 6.0 (SP6) (OLEDB)'` is selected, **not** `'Microsoft Data Bound Grid Control 5.0 (SP3)'`.